# Promise not waiting to finish

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I looked at many examples today. They seem to suggest that the following code should be executed in chain:

```
let f = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        console.log('entering function');
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('resolving');
            res()
        }, 2000)
    });
};

Promise.resolve()
    .then(f())
    .then(f());
```

Expected output would be:

```
entering function
resolving
entering function
resolving
```

But it isn't. The output is

```
entering function
entering function
resolving
resolving
```

and I can't figure out why. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try `then(f)` instead of `then(f())`

`then` expects a function.

you can also do `then(()=>f())`

Comment: Additional help, calling `then(f())` invokes the function straight away