# Why does my recursive function with promises only wait once?

Tags: javascript, promise, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to visualize the "Tower of Hanoi"-problem and tried using promises to make the functions wait for one disc's movement to be animated (which I simulated with setTimeout) before continuing to solve the problem. This test-code calculates the correct movements, but only waits for the animation once and then spits out the rest immediately:

```
    var A = "rod A";
    var B = "rod B";
    var C = "rod C";

    solve(3,A,C,B);

    function solve (n,source,target,spare) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (n==1) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("move a disc from "+source+" to "+target);
                    resolve();
                },1000);
            }
            else {
                        solve(n-1,source,spare,target)
                .then(  solve( 1 ,source,target      )  )
                .then(  solve(n-1,spare,target,source)  )
                .then(  resolve()                       );
            }
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

For people not knowing the problem, I simplified the code a bit, essentially the goal is to print "move" seven times with one second of delay between each of them:

```
    solveTest(3);

    function solveTest (n) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (n==1) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("move");
                    resolve();
                },1000);
            }
            else {
                        solveTest(n-1)
                .then(  solveTest( 1 )  )
                .then(  solveTest(n-1)  )
                .then(  resolve()       );
            }
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

Comment: `.then(resolve())` does not do what you think it does, nor do any of your other function calls as an argument to `.then()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise not waiting to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968311/promise-not-waiting-to-finish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are immediately invoking all of your calls, and then passing their return values as an argument to `.then()`. What you need to do is pass functions to `.then()` that call them instead:

```js
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

function solve (n, source, target, spare) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return sleep(1000).then(function () {
      console.log('move a disc from ' + source + ' to ' + target)
    })
  } else {
    return solve(n - 1, source, spare, target).then(function () {
      return solve(1, source, target, spare)
    }).then(function () {
      return solve(n - 1, spare, target, source)
    })
  }
}

solve(3, 'rod A', 'rod B', 'rod C')
```

But you can make it even easier to read by using `async` and `await`:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, ms) })

async function solve (n, source, target, spare) {
  if (n === 1) {
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log(`move a disc from ${source} to ${target}`)
  } else {
    await solve(n - 1, source, spare, target)
    await solve(1, source, target, spare)
    await solve(n - 1, spare, target, source)
  }
}

solve(3, 'rod A', 'rod B', 'rod C')
```